# php:replace the last value from each line on a list

Tags: php

hi i have a little problem, i want to add a text on the begin and on the end of each line of a textarea:

```
test1,test11,test111,
test2,test22,test222,
test3,test33,test333,
```

so i write this code to add "first" on the begin on each line, but i don't know how to replace the last comma (,) from each line with a text, my code

```
$s=(explode(" ",str_replace("\n","First",$_POST['text'])));
foreach($s as $i=> $ss){
$s[$i]=$ss."<br>";
echo "First".$s[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove the comma, use substr

```
$ss = substr($ss,0,-1);
```

Then add the end and start.

Comment: how?? he dosen't work i can just remove it from the last line on the list

Comment: It doesn't remove the last line from the list. It removes the last character from $ss. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

probably you can do this:

```
$str = 'test1,test11,test111,';
echo substr_replace($str, ",Last", -1);
```

This code will replace the last character in the string with the text you want to replace with ... in this case I have put ",Last".. you may add any text.

Comment: A paragraph (or even a sentence) or two of explanation goes a long way into making a possible correct answer into a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple to understand answer to your question

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['text']); // make an array in which every item is a line
// modifying the lines
foreach($lines as $index => $text) {
    $text = trim($text); // remove any space at the begining or end of the line
    $text = substr($text, 0, strlen($text) - 1); // remove the last character from the line (which is supposed to be the ',')
    $text = "First " . $text . " Last"; // adding first and last part you want
    $lines[$index] = $text; // appling modification of the array $lines
    echo $lines[$index] . "<br>"; // showing the line !
}
```

Comment: thnx broo, it's ok now ;)

Comment: This is a case where I'd use reference in foreach as: foreach($lines as &$text)... then you wouldn't have to set $lines[$index] to $text.

Comment: You're right @kainaw. I just wanted to KISS (keep it simple stupid) :P